# Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, image, transparency

I would like to render an animation as a series of .png images with transparent backgrounds for use in a video. Is this possible?

Comment: One of other settings that can mess your transparent background is something in Composing tab. What I did was set perfect white color there with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aegiN7XeLow And then browse half of the internet, figure out to find the tutorial how I set perfect white background, and than discover I have to remove the middle box from Composing tab. To future me: I got that covered

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

To save rendered images with transparent background (PNG format for instance), the settings are as follows for "Cycles" and  "Blender Render" rendering engines.

### Cycles

*Properties Editor > Render Context > Output Panel*

*Choose RGBA* so that the alpha from the renderer is saved in the png

*Properties Editor > Render Context > Film Panel*

Check Film>*Transparent* so that the World background is transparent.

[image: Saving PNG with alpha using Cycles]

[image]

### Blender Render

*Properties Editor > Render Context > Output Panel*

*Choose RGBA* so that the alpha from the renderer is saved in the png

*Properties Editor > Render Context > Shading Panel*

Choose *Transparent* Alpha type.

[image: Saving PNG with alpha using Blender Internal]

### EEVEE (Blender 2.8)

*Properties Editor > Render Context > Film Panel*

Choose *Transparent* Alpha type.

[image: Saving PNG with alpha using EEVEE]

Comment: This ***is*** the answer.

Comment: It's not working for me (Blender render) and I chose the same options. When I render, all I see is white (the material color).

Comment: One year after, and yet again it helped me.

Comment: Why does blender still spend render time with the tiles on the transparent parts?

Comment: @Anson What I believe is that the camera is shooting rays into the scene and since there is no returning ray , there must be a timeout wait before the render decides to move on to the next square.

Comment: The funny part is that this answer, while covering how, fails only on suggesting PNG as a format. PNG is incapable of preserving alpha from a render because it uses an unassociated alpha format. It is likely precisely because of this that the PNG format has almost exactly zero uptake in visual effects and imaging circles.

Comment: @troy_s You sound like you know what you're talking about, and I'm curious to hear it. Why don't you edit the answer to include some of your insight?

Comment: I can't because the answer is a bit of a trap; PNGs can _never_ render transparency correctly from a technical vantage. Best hope is to educate the imagers around these parts so that they can become aware of the differences in alpha format, and the impact on their work.

Comment: @RegularJoe As you can see from my answer, the Film panel is Cycles renderer specific. It does not show up under Blender renderer.

Comment: @Satishgoda, this is a VERY USEFUL information and thank you.

Comment: @Hikariztw, in Blender 2.8, the Film and Output panels are in two different locations.  The Output panel has been moved from the Render context to the Output Context.

Comment: @mattthew Yeah, I do find out that thing after I press the submit button. Going to add it.

Comment: Thanks for updating also to Blender 2.8 (Eeevee) - very helpful!

Comment: I'm using Eevee with Blender 2.8. I clicked the "Transparent" checkbox in "Film", and I also tried changing the "Alpha" setting of the material, but it's still not transparent.

Comment: Make sure there is no geometry that is obstructing the background.

Comment: @troy_s are you sure PNG's "cant render transparently", or is it merely **Cycles** which can't render the final PNG result transparently? With the removal of the Blender Internal renderer in 2.8, many texture artists find themselves without any tools to bake diffuse/albedo textures that have alpha in them. Hopefully they'll stop ignoring these devs, considering that texture atlasing is incredibly important for games.

Comment: PNG is a broken format and cannot encode things like reflections, glares, flares, fire, etc. Emitting yet unoccluding pixels are simply impossible to encode using the broken format.

Answer (score 24):

In **Blender Internal**, If you want the background to be transparent, you can change the output type to RGBA and in the *Scene* tab under *Layer*, untick *Sky*.

Comment: Unticking "Sky" was what I needed to make it work (I already had RGBA selected). In Blender 2.79 I found this setting on the "Render Layers" context.

Answer (score 14):

In the render settings go under Shading and set alpha to transparent. Then under output click RGBA. Unchecking Sky in the scene tab will also work but I'm not sure if that method will have an impact on any other parts of the render or if it's just a redundancy.

Comment: Where do you see that? I don't see any Shading section, but I do see Sampling, AO, Bloom, DoF, Subsurface Scattering, SSR, Motion Blur, Volumetrics, Hair, Shadows, Indirect Lighting, Film, Simplify, Freestyle, and Color Management.

Answer (score 3):

when using luxcore render in Blender, in Camera panel, turn on checkbox 'Transparent Film' (settings is different for each camera)
[image]

in output panel, choose PNG format and RGBA (alpha)
[image]