# Composite transparent overlapping objects from different scenes?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, node-editor

Following on from this question `[Can I use Cycles materials with Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal) When following the instructions the solution worked fine but when i tried to apply it to multiple windows I came across this problem

[image]

[*(larger image here)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6yT3.jpg)

When I render the picture (F12) as you can see the glass has no effect on the first picture and the glass can be seen through the mesh of my wall. So I added an add node and I got the effect of the glass to show but no matter what I have tried to do I still cannot get the back windows to be hidden behind the mesh of the front wall. Is there a way to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue your having is masking. You have to have a mask of some sort to get the windows behind the rest of the building. I've come up with a (rather imperfect) solution, as long as you assign a different material to the inside of the building. **Note that the following is assuming that you have completed the steps in "[Can I use Cycles materials with Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal)"**

1. In the outside building material for "scene", scroll down to options and set *Pass Index* to 1 (or 2 or whatever, as long as nothing else in the scene has the same pass number).[image: pass index]
2. Create a second indoor material and assign it's pass index to something other than 2 (or leave it at the default 0).
3. Go to your render layers and enable *Material Index*.
   [image: enable material index in the render layers]
4. Rerender the scene and go to the compositor. You should now see a new plug output called *IndexMA*.
5. Add an *IDMask* node, plug in *IndexMA* to *IDValue* and set *Index* to whatever value the outdoor material's index is (and check anti-aliasing).
6. Add an Invert node and plug in the output of the IDMask node.
7. Plug the output of the of the Invert node into the *Fac* of the Alpha over node.
   [image: node setup]

Comment: Thank you worked a treat but I have a question. If you are going to render a scene but have no intention of going onto the house could i insert 2 planes (making them transparent) and call them indoor material and out door material would it still have the same effect or would the transparancy cancel the effect out.:-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Z-Combine node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Color#Z-Combine_Node)

> The Z-Combine node takes two images and two Z-value sets as input. It overlays the images using the provided Z values to detect which parts of one image are in front of the other. If both Z values are equal, it uses the top image. It puts out the combined image, with the combined Z-depth map, allowing you to thread multiple Z-combines together.

To use <kbd>Add | Color | Z Combine</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and then connect up your render layers.

[image: Minimal basic node setup using z-combine node.]

For best results then using BI scenes you'll also want to enable [Full Sample](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Options/Antialiasing) (found under Properties window > Render tab > Anti-Aliasing panel).

> #### Full Sample
>
> For every anti-aliasing sample, save the entire Render Layer results. This solves anti-aliasing issues with compositing.