# What is the workflow for compositing Fire/Smoke with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation

Since fire/smoke is currently only supported in the internal renderer, what are some good workflow ideas for bringing fire and smoke into a cycles scene.

My current idea seems too labor intensive:

Rendering out the Cycles frames, then duplicating the scene, setting the renderer to internal and changing all of the materials to masking alpha. Then compositing the frames together.

Is there a better way until volumetrics are added to cycles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composite transparent overlapping objects from different scenes?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/composite-transparent-overlapping-objects-from-different-scenes)

Comment: No I can composite 2 scenes no problem. The question is more about scene setup workflow. Having to have 2 sets of materials for the objects in the scene that will be rendered via cycles is a hassle.

Comment: thats simple prepare your animation in cycles with cycles material,duplicate your scene full copy,leave all cycles material on place put fire on place you need and render in BI cycles material will be ivisible and crate mask just set backround black and finaly composite both scenes

Comment: I was hoping to be able to easily link everything but the materials, that way I can still make tweaks to the animation/etc without having to completely redo BI sim stuff.

Comment: BTW, blender cookie made a [tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/10/10/compositing-smoke-simulations-cycles-renders/) on this recently

Comment: This looks pretty much like what you're looking for: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/10/10/compositing-smoke-simulations-cycles-renders/ (it's a free tutorial) Haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [tobkum's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3296/599), an example workflow using the technique in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNUYSMP97fg) might be:

1. Setup BI scene (simulation, etc.)
2. Create a new scene for Cycles, with *Link object data*
3. Create Cycles materials, linking to *Object* instead of *Data* so BI and cycles materials are not synced:

   [image]
4. In the BI scene:

   4. Create BI materials, again using *Object* instead of *Data*.
   5. Disable shadows for all BI materials except the smoke
   6. Create renderlayers for smoke and smoke shadows using the *Shadow* pass.
   7. Create renderlayers for reflections and refractions, and remove sky by setting the *Horizon color* to black.
5. Setup compositing in Cycles scene:

   1. Create renderlayers for foreground and background objects
   2. Multiply BI shadows with cycles background layer
   3. Alpha over BI smoke over cycles background layer
   4. Alpha over cycles foreground layer over composite
   5. Add or Mix BI reflections and refractions to composite
6. Render

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.73 it is now supported and has become much easier, see my answer here:

[Rendering smoke in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424)