# Render only a certain part of a frame, reuse the rest of the frame from the frame rendered before

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have ~800 frames which are technically still. In these 800 frames, only a small section of it moves, is it possible to only render the first frame fully, then only re-render the small moving part of the 799 frames left and reuse the rest of the image from the first rendered frame?

I want this rendered for 800 frames

[image: I want to render this for 800 frames]

Only this part moves for those 800 frames[image]

Comment: Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33903/3710 ?

Comment: related: [render-just-part-of-a-final-image](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301/render-just-part-of-a-final-image-from-cycles?rq=1), and  [render-borders](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work)

Comment: I normally split the scene's object to forground and background, placed in different layers, then render the background once, and the foreground every time - and composite them together in the compositor. http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-compositor/

Also:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/composite-transparent-overlapping-objects-from-different-scenes/1907#1907

Comment: @TLousky Hey you seem to know a lot about blender... Is there any way I can contact you so you can help me?

Comment: @bi0phaz3, I don't know more than the other people who commented on your question, but you're welcome to contact me here on the private chat.

Comment: @TLousky how do I access this private chat?

Comment: @TLousky how do I use the compositor to do what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by separating the foreground and background elements and rendering them separately, then using the compositor to re-combine them.

[Result of this approach](http://listenonrepeat.com/watch/?v=j4uDsN1tntU#Answer_to_question_about_composting_on_stack_overflow)

First, render only the very background - the object(s) that is behind everything else, and save to file:
[image: Background]

Then, [make sure you set the background to transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent).

Then render the static foreground elements (the elements above everything else that aren't animated) and save to file:
[image: Static foreground]

Now you can render your dynamic, animated element separately from the rest. Make sure you render to an image sequence of PNGs with transparent background:
[image: Animated part]

Now all you need to do is open the compositor and use alpha over nodes to composite the static and dynamic elements, then render it all out together to one video file (or a new image sequence):
[image: Node setup]

Alternative node setup using Z combine:
[image]

You can find the [blend file that was used for this answer](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/552/) here. Good luck!

Comment: Please use a more permanent blend file storage like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ; the links do not expire there whereas pasteall links do after 5 months.

Comment: Will rendering the background image once, and putting the swirling DNA is another layer and using Z Combine to join the static image and the swirling DNA together also work?

Comment: Also, you put a lot of effort into answering my simple question, taking your time to remodel the model and uploading a video showing the result. I thank you very much and I very much appreciate your help kind sir. Very satisfying

Comment: Goot point @RayMairlot, updated.@bi0phaz3: you're welcome, wish I started out doing amazing 3D as early as you, good luck! :)

Comment: @TLousky Thanks, and also, will the Z Combine method work too?

Comment: @bi0phaz3 - Yup, sure will: https://bioblog3d.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/z_combine.jpg

Comment: Thanks @TLousky, I think I can replace the image sequence with a RenderLayer input so I don't have to render the image sequence then combine, which takes more time. And so if I'm not mistake, higher Z-Values will be placed further into the background, letting images with less Z-Values overlay it?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea @bi0phaz3. And yes, higher values mean further into the background.