# How can I move an object on a separate layer behind another in the compositor?

Tags: workflow, compositing-nodes, render-layers

How can I make the light bar, after compositing (applying the blur effect on it), be displayed behind the ball, not in front of it?

[image]

Comment: First off, recognize the reason *why* it's doing this - or appearing to. It's because you're using the *Add* blend mode, and your bar is quite light. That realization will help you find the solution (use alpha over, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

## ID Mask:

Expanding on [Gunslinger's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3094/599), this can be done on two render layers, using an [*ID Mask* node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor#ID_Mask_Node):

1. With the foreground object selected, set the *Pass index* to `1` in *Object properties > Relations*:

   [image: pass index image]
2. Enable the *Object index* pass in *Render Layers > Passes*:

   [image: passes image]
3. Add an *ID Mask* node and set the *Index* to `1`.
4. Plug the *IndexOB* output from the Renderlayer node into the *ID Mask* node. This will provide a mask for the foreground object:

   [image: mask node]
5. Mix:

   [image: Simple mix setup]

   Gunslinger's setup is better as it preserves the sky:

   [image: Gunslinger's mix setup with ID mask]

### Result:

[image: rendered result]

Note that you can also use ID masks on a material basis.
Enable *Material index* in *Render layers > Passes*, and set the pass index for the material:

Use *Materials > Settings > Pass index* to set the pass index of the material in Cycles:

[image: cycles material pass index]

Or in Blender internal use *Materials > Options > Pass index*:

[image: BI material pass index]

Answer (score 2):

If, you are rendering with ***Blender Internal***, one way to go about this is to go to the render layers with the ball and the bar and under *Layer*, untick *Sky* for both. Since this will remove the background from both those layers, just create another *RenderLayer* that will just be the sky.

[image]

Now if you use an *Alpha Over* node, you can choose which object appears over which one by switching the inputs. You will then use another *Alpha Over* node to get back the background.

[image]

For Cycles, you can get the same results by making sure that *Use Environment* is ticked under *Layer* and then ticking *Transparent* under *Film*, this will affect all render layers however it seems so perhaps you can use an image as the second input for the second *Alhpa Over* node, *just render out a nice gradient etc and load it back in as an image*.

Comment: Thanks. But unticking Sky for them make their backgrounds black not transparent. On the other hand, ticking Transparent under Film make the three layers' backgrounds transparent.

Comment: Not sure how you're getting that, it should be transparent. Try going to _Render_ > _Output_ and changing it from _RGB_ to _RGBA_. If that doesn't do anything, please upload and share the blend-file, it is possible you changed something elsewhere.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B64HAX4F6H-YTmlra0otX3VXckE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jikk In the future, please specify what render engine you are using. I very rarely use Cycles so i'm not able to really help in regards to that and it seems that [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent) doesn't work so i'm not sure. This answer only applies to the Internal Renderer.

Comment: @Jikk Actually, it seems when using Cycles, you need to tick _Use Environment_ under _Layer_ and _Transparent_ under _Film_ to get the background transparent as I saw in that answer but this will affect all render layers. So perhaps you can still do this but instead of using a blender sky, use an image as the background with the second _Alpha Over_ node.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for bothering you! The answers below seem confusing to me since I am very new to Blender. Can you please mimic the material settings for the ball and light bar using Internal Engine? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jikk It would be best if you asked that as a separate question as you are more likely to get better answers that way. I added a simple workaround if using Cycles to the answer, did you try that? Also see, [Can I use Cycles materials with Blender Internal?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal). If the answers seem confusing, please use the comments section to request clarification from the authors. :)

Comment: @Jikk Both answers below are the same for both BI and Cycles. The only things you should have to change are the *Renderlayers*, *Compositing nodes*, and in the case of my answer, the *Pass index* value in the material settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to render another pass with only the ball, call it mask. Override the material to be pure black.

Multiply the line with this renderpass. Before or after the blur node if you want the glow to overlap the ball slightly, or not.

Note! (if I have time tonite, I will update the screenshot). The background of the mask must of course be white, else it will dim the line.

Node setup here:
[image: Node setup]

Comment: Instead of rerendering the ball/cube, why not use a [id mask node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor#ID_Mask_Node) with a object or material index?

Comment: You are right. I just couldn't figure it out.