# How to use an object as a mask?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, masking

I have a 4 point plane (quadratic) that I would like to use as a mask when rendering.I need this so the mask will be transformed correctly when I move the camera. This plane is covering the area I would like to mask.

I was thinking to maybe render a mask scene and feed that into the final scene as a mask. But since Blender now has masks, it would be easier if we could convert a mesh into a mask.

**EDIT
I'm using Blender 2.68a with Cycles.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3092/599

Comment: You could give it a *Holdout* material, this will make the object render as transparency.

Comment: @gandalf3 You should probably make this an answer ;)

Comment: The project is on ice so I haven't tried it yet. I don't know if it solved my problem.

Comment: Searching the manual I found the following manual entries: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/render/layers/passes.html The explanation of ID Masks together with the list of passes and the information that you need to use cycles as renderer should bring you in a position where you are able to set everything up as explained.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using the Object ID and a ID mask node.

Select the object you want to use as a mask, and under the object tab in the properties set the Pass Index unequal 0 (I used 1, but if you have more then one mask give each one a different number)

[image: Object Tab]

Now, head over to the RenderLayers tab and check the Object ID pass

[image: RenderLayers Tab]

Re-render your image and head over to the node editor. There attach a ID Mask node to the IndexOB socket. Use the node's output as a factor for a mix node (See screenshot)

[image: Node Setup]

Here I used a test image, but you can use one from any source you want.

[image: Example Output]

Comment: I see how you think :) I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: The interface is very different today, and I can't even find the render layers or id mask nodes? Is this still possible? I'm trying to cut some hair using a cube... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209038/cut-hair-particles-using-boolean-modifier