# Compositor: make the glare node effect only certain objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want some objects to be affected by the glare node in my scene but not all of the objects in the scene to be effected by it. But the problem with that is the glare node is used in the render layers panel so it effects the whole scene when I put the glare node in when I only want the glare node to effect certain objects. Is there a way around this? (This is in blender cycles).[image]

Example Image Above

Comment: We need a screenshot of your compositor node setup

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860#35860

Comment: Done, I edited the post and placed an image.

Comment: So what parts of the image should glow?

Comment: That was just an example, I hid everything else in other layers, but I just want to know how to make any object you want to glow, and any object that you don't want to glow because by default when the set up is like that it makes everything glow, but I want to know how to make different objects glow.

Comment: The key is separating objects, either via object ID masks, render layers or any other method, then applying your desired effect only to the objects you want. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask/3515#3515 or this whole tut: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-compositor/

Comment: to use id masks, see http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/converter/id_mask.html

Answer (score 5):

If you render those objects on a separate layer you can apply the glare just apply glare to that render layer.

E.g.
[image: Render Layer example]