# Any idea how to get the location and bounds of object in the image?

Tags: python

I am drawing a line of vehicles on the image, how could I get the coordinates and bounds of each vehicle in the image, since I want to crop the these vehicles one by one from this image?[image]

I found a snippet, but the values (x , y, width, height) seem to be like the global coordinates rather than the pixel position on the image.

```
def get_bounds(ob):
    mat = ob.matrix_world
    bbox = [mat * Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box]

    min_x = min(b.x for b in bbox)
    max_x = max(b.x for b in bbox)
    min_y = min(b.y for b in bbox)
    max_y = max(b.y for b in bbox)

    top_left = Vector((min_x, max_y))
    bottom_right = Vector((max_x, min_y))

    # make flat tuple, x y width height
    return top_left.to_tuple() + tuple(map(abs, (top_left - bottom_right)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by analyzing each isolated object in the compositor after rendering, [via an object ID mask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask/3515#3515).

The compositor gives you [access to the pixels of the viewer node](https://ammous88.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/blender-access-render-results-pixels-directly-from-python-2/), which can be manipulated quickly in Numpy.

[Blendfile here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/561/)

This is the rendered image:
[image]

I gave each of the objects a different pass index, so we generate a mask that isolates each in turn with the ID mask node.

[image: Node setup]

By changing the index in the ID mask node you can iterate between the objects. Here's object 1's mask:
[image: Obj1 mask]

Now, to get the bounding box coordinates all you need to do is run this script (partially based [on this nice method for producing a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808221/is-there-a-bounding-box-function-slice-with-non-zero-values-for-a-ndarray-in)):

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

S = bpy.context.scene
width  = int( S.render.resolution_x * S.render.resolution_percentage / 100 )
height = int( S.render.resolution_y * S.render.resolution_percentage / 100 )
depth  = 4

pixels = np.array( bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels[:] ).reshape( [height, width, depth] )

# Keep only one value for each pixel (white pixels have 1 in all RGBA channels anyway), thus converting the image to black and white
pixels = np.array( [ [ pixel[0] for pixel in row ] for row in pixels ] )

bbox = np.argwhere( pixels )
(ystart, xstart), (ystop, xstop) = bbox.min(0), bbox.max(0) + 1
```

Output I got for this image:

```
>>> ystart
157

>>> xstart
273

>>> ystop
380

>>> xstop
398
```