# Can i render particles from one object on 2 different render layers?

Tags: rendering, particles, layers

I am following one of CG Geek's tutorials about Fall Road and i am having a problem with final render. There are about 6 different particles systems on one object and my PC just can't handle it. It freezes when i try to render. I was wondering if i could somehow move some of these particles systems to different layers so i could render them one by one and then connect them in composition?

Comment: Are you sure it freezes and doesn't just take a long time to setup before it starts rendering?

Comment: Well, i am not 100% sure, but i've waited for 30 min and it still was on synchronizing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no settings to define which render layer a particle system is render on, the particles will all show on the **same layer as the emitting object**.

You could setup multiple objects, each with their own particle system and placed on a separate layer so you can render them separately. By using the same mesh, the particles can emit from the same positions and parenting the duplicate objects to the main object will let you move them all together. You can also disable selection of the duplicates so you can only select the parent object. The particle systems on each duplicate object would then have the render emitter disabled to prevent them from showing in the render, so you don't get [z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21/935).

[image: emitter disabled]

Comment: Well, i am a newbie so could you explain how can i do it step by step? I duplicated my object and moved it to another layer, then unchecked emitter, but it still was visible so i created mask modfier on it and then i rendered it, but i don't know how can i "merge" those render layers together. I tried in composition, but it just makes one of the layers partially invisible

Comment: You could start with the [blenderguru introduction to compositing](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-compositor/) his recent [rendering onto an image](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background/) also applies. You can find several examples here, [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19767/935) explains getting scene layers onto a render layer, [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3515/935) shows using an objectID as a mask when mixing layers.

Comment: Well i don't know if i did everything good, but at least i finished it :D Thank you for your help.
Here are the results
[fall road](http://imgur.com/5vt4FL9)