# Cut hair particles using boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers, particles, hair

[image]

I've sculpted a head and added some hair particles to half a sphere positioned on top of the head. This all works fine.

I now modeled a hat and placed it on top of the hair. Obviously the hair goes through the hat.

So I figured I'd just add a boolean modifier to the hair emitter and cut the hair using a cube but I can't get it to work.

Is it not possible to slice hair using a boolean modifier?

Is there another way I can achieve  the same thing?

Edit: I got the boolean modifier to work (it was in the wrong order at first) but instead of cutting the hair it obviously cuts the actual hair *emitter* instead, resulting in the troll going bald :P

I also tried the collision tip in the comments, but that just made the hair go crazy and still clip through the hat :/

Comment: The boolean modifier will not cut hair, but Shape Cut will: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/mode.html However, why not just make the hat kill particles it touches in physics Collision?

Comment: Oh that kill particles thing sounds promising I will try that. So I need to set the hat to physics -> collision and in there somewhere specify that it should kill the hair? If you could explain a little further in an answer that'd be awesome!

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/collision.html?highlight=kill%20particles

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, and while the hair did collide with the hat it made the hair go all over the place and still cut through the hat :/ I've added an image to explain further.

Comment: Enable "kill particles" in the Collision settings

Comment: Yea I did that too.