# Remove reflection of one object from another object?

Tags: compositing-nodes, layers, render-layers

I have a reflective object and I want it to reflect only light and not the surrounding objects.

I have moved it to Layer `2`, but it still reflects the objects from layer `1`. What should I do to prevent objects on Layer `1` from casting reflections on objects in Layer `2`?

Answer (score 6):

## Cycles:

Set the renderlayer with the reflective object to *[Exclude](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Passes#Layers)* layer one:

[image]

Now objects on layer `1` will not have any affect on layer `2`.

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26575)

## Blender Internal:

In BI this is more complicated, because it appears to be impossible to separate reflections into separate layers with BI.

In other words, you can either reflect every object in the scene, or reflect nothing (no selective reflecting). You might be able to do something with the *Material Index* pass, but with even a simple scene it becomes complex quickly.

As a workaround, you can use multiple *[Scenes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Scenes)*.

1. Create a new scene in the *Info panel* by pressing the `+`:

   [image]

   Select one of the options. You probably want *Link Objects*, but check [the wiki for an explanation of each option](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Scenes#Adding_a_new_Scene).
2. In the new scene, setup a renderlayer that only renders objects on layer 1.
3. Back in the first scene, setup a renderlayer which has only the reflective object. Put objects you do want to reflect **on a different layer**, but in the same scene.
4. Mix the two scenes with an *Alpha over* node:

   [image]

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26577)

Comment: Okay, I thought I was done, but no, I still can't build a composite layer from the two layers in Cycles without background on the top layer interfering. I need to apply "mask transparency" to my top layer so that the background in that layer is rendered as transparent, but I haven't yet figured out how to do this in Cycles.

Comment: @AnnaClawson You can make the *Sky* transparent by enabling *Transparent* in *Render Settings > Film*

Comment: that's exactly what I tried to do! But it made sky transparent on all the layers instead of just on the top layer.

Comment: @AnnaClawson You can add the background back in with compositing, or you could try *Zmask* instead.

Comment: Your answer on another thread explains pretty well how to do masking in Cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-can-i-move-an-object-on-a-separate-layer-behind-another-in-the-compositor/3099#3099

Comment: @AnnaClawson Thanks :) here's another [example file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26589) with the sky and the objects mixed together using a separate scene (which is another way to do it).