# Make object glossy, but not reflect other object's colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Cycles, I would like to make a metal object have a shiny, glossy material. The only thing is, other object's colors reflect off of this metal object.

I would like to make it glossy, but not reflect any other colors.

How do I do this?

Comment: what do you want it to reflect ?

Comment: Well.. nothing, just light, not colors. Like I want to make it have those highlights and reflect light so there is a bit of "white reflection" to this black-colored object, but not reflect colors like purple and red, etc.

Comment: you can disable other objects from appearing as reflection if they are not needed in other things

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: select the object , go to object tab->Ray_Visibility and uncheck Glossy

Comment: You can turn off glossy reflection for each of your other objects but that's not very good practise because you may want them to reflect on each other. In blender internal this can be done though. See this answer, it asks the same in a more general sense http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/remove-reflection-of-one-object-from-another-object/6646#6646

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by preventing other objects from appearing as a reflection on any glossy material by disabling the **Glossy** option in :  **Properties**➩**Object**➩**Ray_Visibility**

[image]