# Cycles selective reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have bottle, "table" and it all lit by environment texture (HDRi). How to setup scene so that the world texture affect the bottle but is invisible (doesn't reflect the table)? The only object reflecting in table should be the bottle. I've tryed the Light Path node for the table, but without luck.

Comment: take a look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/remove-reflection-of-one-object-from-another-object

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403 and maybe: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34532/problem-with-transparency-when-using-two-world-images/34535#34535

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple way for doing this because blender doesn't have proper ligth linking settings. You can try uncheck glossy from the ray visibility of your world,
but that's not ideal.

What you can do is put your HDR on two sphere objects, instead of world.
One of them with glossy uncheck from visibility rays.

Have two render layer one for the table the other one for the glass and exclude the reflective world for the first one.