# Cannot blur one render layer and then Z-combine it with another layer

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, blur

this is driving me crazy. I want the trails in this scene to glow:

[image: nodes problem]

But when plugging the trails into the z combine node the blur is removed. If you have an idea why that is and what I can do to fix it I would be much obliged.

Many Thanks for your answers! Here is what happened:

Not using Alpha results in this:

[image: alpha with nodes]

The blur is there but it is behind the geometry.

I already tried blurring the Z pass before and it turned out like this:

[image]

The Map Range nodes are necessary because otherwise the Z blur would just turn out white. There is some blur visible but the rest is messed up.

I think the problem is that the blurred render layer is wrapped by the unblurred render layer. This is what Gandalfs example would look like when putting a cube in front and one behind the blurred one:

[image]

Comment: Try disabling *Use Alpha*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either disable *Use Alpha* or blur the Z as well:

[image]

---

## Update

As pointer out by the OP, the above solution does not work when there is geometry behind the glowing object.

Here are some alternative methods roughly in order of number of steps needed to set up:

## 1. [ID Mask](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor):

This method is probably the quickest as it doesn't even require more than one renderlayer.

1. Enable the *Object Index* pass in *Properties > Renderlayers > Passes*:

   [image]
2. Select the object(s) you want to blur and set the *Pass Index* to a unique number so that no other objects have the same *Pass Index*.

   [image]
3. In the compositor, add an *ID Mask* node and set the *Index* to the same number you set the objects:

   [image]

Also see this [related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3092/599).

## 2. Z-Mask:

You'll notice that in method one that the glow appears in front of other objects:

[image]

You may want this effect or you may not. If you don't, then you can use the *Zmask* in *Properties > Renderlayers > Layer*:

- Background objects are on Layer 1
- Foreground objects are on layer 2
- Glow objects are on layer 3

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. What makes your example different: There is no geometry behind the blurred cube. See the screenshot I added to my question.

Comment: @gandalf3 thank you so much for posting this answer. I'd never have solved a similar issue I was having with out it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97048/44673