# How can I render a light source with a composite fog glow but not blur an object?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I seem to have boxed myself into a corner after spending a week of rendering and setting up.

I created a mountain scene with an icosphere (emission material) flying through the canyons, all is fine so far. To get a glow effect on the sphere I used composited with fog glow to get this result.

**ORB flying down canyons**

[image]

At a certain set point the sphere then hovers beside a LEGO castle and this is where I am having terrible trouble. The render is:

**Castle is mixed in screen option on mix node**

[image]

And in my node setup I can see that the screen option on the mix node is the problem.

**Node Setup - Castle is mixed in screen mode**

[image]

So to help speed up rendering I tried to render just the castle and light source and add the landscape in compositing but I just get:

**No landscape**

[image]

**Node setup - no landscape**

[image]

I then tried to use render layers but got nowhere.

How can I render a light source with a composite fog glow but not blur an object? And if possible also use compositing to add the landscape after to cut down on render times?

**PROGRESS**

I managed to get the castle to render with out the fog glow effect but I still cannot get the background to work. The last mix node is set to mix and if I change it to add the castle looks semi transparent.

**Set to Mix**

[image]

**Set to Add**

[image]

Comment: render the light source in a different layer, that way whatever you do to it (like blur or glow) it will not affect other layers.

Comment: Hi, the light source is on a different later. It's the compositor that is adding the fog effect and I don't know how to tell the compositor to ignore the castle later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use ID Mask with the emission object set to index 1 and use an Alpha Over node to place my transparent render on the background.

All credit to @gandalf3 for this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7170/44673).

[image]

Comment: Putting this here for anyone interested in the full animation
https://youtu.be/UuJD6HEIt8c