# How to put 2 parts of 1 object on different layers?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have single object (human model), but I want legs and arms to be in different layers so I can composite it in compositor. I don't want to break it into different object.

Comment: You have to have the entire object on the same layer. But you can assign different materials to each part of the mesh and use a pass index as [described here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3099/935) to separate them in the compositor.

Comment: @sambler Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @gandalf3 your linked answer explains it, only difference would be to put the material index at the top.

Comment: @sambler Hm.. True.. Idk what to do. Should I add an answer which just quotes my other answer?

Comment: @gandalf3 It's almost a duplicate question. You could say "set material index then composite as explained..."

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move different parts of the same object to separate layers.

As [mentioned by sambler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-to-put-2-parts-of-1-object-on-different-layers?noredirect=1#comment16303_11062), what you are trying to do is possible using separate materials to generate masks.

Quoting from my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3099/599):

> This can be done . . . using an [*ID Mask* node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor#ID_Mask_Node):
>
> . . .
>   1. Enable *Material index* in *Render layers > Passes*, and set the pass index for the material:
>
> - Use *Materials > Settings > Pass > index* to set the pass index of the  material in Cycles:
>
>   [image: cycles material pass index]
> - Or in Blender internal use *Materials > Options > Pass index*:
>
>   [image: BI material pass index]
>
> 3. Add an *ID Mask* node and set the *Index* to `1`.
> 4. Plug the *IndexOB* output from the Renderlayer node into the *ID Mask* node. This will provide a mask for the [material]:
>      [image: mask node]

This will give you a black and white mask of that material, which you can use to separate, combine, etc. in the compositor using mix nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can be moved from one layer to the next.  Mesh elements(vertices, edges, and faces) cannot, since they are apart of the same object.

The only option I can think of for your situation is to use vertex groups.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Vertex_Groups

Comment: Thank you, but how do I move it to other layer?

Comment: You can't, you have to find ways to separate the parts in the compositor without layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move part of an object to a different layer. You can split it into 2 different object by selecting the vertices you want to separate in edit mode and hitting the **P key** separate by selection.

Now that you have 2 objects, in object mode place them in different layers by selecting the objects you want to move and hitting the **M key** then a number (not from the keypad).

Use a **Number** to select from the upper row or **ALT + Number** for the lower one

[image]

Comment: I think everything apart from the first sentence is exactly what he doesn't want to do.