# removing shadows between layers

Tags: rendering, layers

Wow, I got excited when I finally gave up and got help with this problem. I found the exact solution on a previous post:

[image]

The question was how to keep the shadow of an object in one layer from being casted onto another object in another layer. I wanted to keep the shadow of layer two from casting onto the object in layer one, so I figured it would be done as so:

[image]

The problem is that it did't work. I've spent hours trying to select every possible combo of buttons and scouring the web and I can't get it. I need to quit being like a stubborn mule sometimes and know when to get help. Any of which would be much appresh.

Comment: whoops, this might help. Using cycles in 2.71

Comment: Ok, I kinda got it to work. Seems to every now and again to not work. Could be a bug. Either way, when it does work I try to press the right layer and exclude buttons so other objects in the fourth or 5th layer don't have any effect on the other layers and blender throws a hissy. So i don't know what I'm going to do about that. Please help

Comment: I know this question is old, but in case you still want an answer, is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Comment: I don't think I can load a file because I don't have enough points or experience or however they gauge your rank on this page. I don't see one anyway.

Comment: There currently isn't anyway to upload files to this site, you'll have to use another hosting site like http://pasteall.org/blend and post the link here.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded boomerang6_ja12.blend to that site.

Comment: Hm.. looks like a 0 byte file :/ Also in the future remember to put the URL here ;) Pasteall names files with an incrementing number, so there is no way to tell where it is with just the filename.. (I guessed it this time by uploading a file and then changing the URL to the previous file, which happened to be yours..)

Comment: Ok, I re-downloaded the file. It should be at http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32340

Comment: The file seems to work for me, but I'm not to sure what you want it to do.. Anyway, I'd recommend avoiding extra renderlayers whenever possible, as they increase render time. I think you could take advantage of [material index masks](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3099/599) here.

Comment: Thanks. I had heard of these magic material index masks before and checked it out just before I finished the project. Don't know if I have that kind of time to put into the project. I write and do CG as a weekend warrior to promote books and build franchise. If I get more time I will check it out. Thanks again ;)