# rendering partial mesh object

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I am rendering a shoe by stitching its parts and displaying on the browser, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

How this works is, a python script reads the blend file containing the shoe model, and spits out each part of the shoe as a `.png` file. This is again stitched back at the frontend. I am however having a problem while rendering the shoe in certain angles at the frontend, for instance the back-view angle as shown in the below image:
[image]

For this angle, I want the part **SHOE-FRONT** rendered partially as shown in the screenshot below, so that there is no overlapping when these images are stitched and displayed to the user in the browser.

[image]

It is however, getting rendered as shown below:
[image]

This is creating a overlap between the SHOE-BASE and SHOE-FRONT when displayed in the browser. This is just one use-case. Similar kind of issues exist for every angle of the shoe displayed. I want my blender python script to render the mesh models in a partially visible manner, only those that is visible to the user when viewed in a given angle. Can this partial rendering of a mesh object be achieved with blender python scripting? I tried playing with transparency and alpha modes. But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of

- Render Layers
- Object ID
- compositing

These posts helped me to accomplish a simular case:

- [How to use an object as a mask?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask)
- [How can I move an object on a separate layer behind another in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-can-i-move-an-object-on-a-separate-layer-behind-another-in-the-compositor)