# how do you render falling snow (particles) in cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I can't get the snow I made to be visible in the final animation.[image]

Comment: See my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45487/5705) on how to render particles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particles are just points in space, by default have no geometry or anything for light to interact with so they do not render.  There are [several ways](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45487/5705) to render particles, but for your case I would use *Object* particles.

First create the object you want to use for the snowflakes.  The level of detail depends on how close and in focus the snowflakes will be, but for most applications a simple circle with 8 vertices should work fine.

Next go to the *Render* rollout of the particle system and select *Object* and select the snowflake object to use for the particles.

[image]

Comment: @aoifec250  Glad I could help!  To mark that this question has been solved you can mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons.