# Switched from cycles to blender, made render turn black and white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, color

Hi so I was creating something in cycles and then I realized that I needed to use the halo material for an effect and so switched back to blender render but now when I try to render the picture it comes out as black and white (it came out in color in cycles) I have the render settings set to RGBA but it doesn't work in RGB either.

Please help
Cheers

Also a side question, although cycles is better than blender from what ive read they both have different unique features so which is better for what?

Comment: Cycles and Internal are not interchangeable

Comment: Halo materials can also be rendered using volume scatter and emission shaders in the volume socket for the material. In the case of particles using a point density node. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question directly but a possible work-around:
To get a similar look to halo particles still using Cycles Render I often use a material node setup like this. So for a particle system with a kind of basic halo as the particles just create a sphere with this as the material and select object as the particle type under the 'Render' tab and use the sphere you created as the object.[image: Pseudo Halo Node Setup]
Take note of the 'Blend' value in the 'Layer Weight' node. It was increased from the default 0.5 to about 0.9 to get a softer edge. Tweaking this value, the curve and the emission value should get something to your liking.