# Can't find settings for halo rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm using Blender 2.81 and I can't find halo rendering or anything except surface even after changing the rendering engine to Cycles.[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Halo and Wireframe rendering are only supported in Blender Internal render engine which has been removed in Blender 2.8 and later

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Blender version 2.8 the blender internal render engine has been discontinued. So there is and will not be an option like halos or wireframe anymore.

versions 2.79 and older:

[image]

## To use something similar in the cycles render engine read:

[Halo particles don't render in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles)

[How do you create an aura, or halo effect, like what was possible with the internal Blender Render Engine, in 2.80](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158474/how-do-you-create-an-aura-or-halo-effect-like-what-was-possible-with-the-inter)

[Blender cycles won't render halo particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/blender-cycles-wont-render-halo-particles/45514#45514)

and

[What is a Point Density texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46717/what-is-a-point-density-texture/47899#47899)