# Can't get my icosphere to render as a halo

Tags: materials

Not sure why I can't seem to turn my selected object (icosphere) to a halo when I try to make a new material.  The options just aren't showing.  Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vesp6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ***Cycles Render*** mode. Switch it to ***Blender Render*** and the options you want'll apppear.
[image]

Comment: But then how do I preview the scene in cycles with the halo effect showing?

Comment: Creating the halo effect like this in Cycles Render is not as simple as in Blender Render. Please see this answer to understand how it works in Cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/blender-cycles-wont-render-halo-particles

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Cycles there is no halo material. You'd need to make one with a particle system:

[image]

Static particles would work best for this, so you can disable physics. Set the render to Halo.

Then you need to add an object that contains the area where you want the particles. Give that object an emission shader connected to the volume of the material, and add a Texture->Point Density node that uses the particle system of the icosphere. plug the density to the strength of the emission shader:

[image]

Comment: Great I got something like this working now...how do I disperse the particles to look like stars, i.e. stucci effect?