# Is There A Cycles Alternative For The Halo Material Effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Just wondering if there is a cycles alternative for the 'halo' material effect only found in Blender Internal? This halo effect turns an object into small glowing orbs instead of one solid object. I am looking for this effect to include in a cycles animation, however the halo option is not available for cycles at all.

I've attached the .blend file to show the halo effect I'm trying to achieve in cycles.

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: What you should do is add another render layer which uses blender internal and blend your passes with compositing.. nodes like alpha-over can help you use the alpha of and object (and if i remember well the zdepth) to create the illusion that it belongs to another scene.
Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/how-can-i-do-glowing-halo-particles-special-effects-in-cycles?rq=1

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles

Comment: the exact thing you want to do can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45802/1853