# how to combine blender internal and cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, light

How can we combine the two render engines to make one scene affect the other? Especially, since cycles doesn't do halos, how can we make it so that the halos created with the internal, enlighten a scene in cycles? For instance, if we created a bunch of firefiles rendered with the internal and have to make it so that a room rendered with cycles have to be enlightened with the fireflies, how do we achieve it?

Comment: The [point density node](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJietAeINTc) can give a halo effect in cycles.

Comment: to render halos in cycles please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/blender-cycles-wont-render-halo-particles

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to render every image two times: one in Internal and one in Cycles, and then combine them in the compositor, using transparency instead of sky for the overlay images (and series of PNG's as format).

Comment: actually I'm asking how will the lighting of the internal affect of that in cycles? How will the light lit in the internal make way to the cycles scene, and I have tried as you said compositing the two images, but rendering and compositing the two images ex: small fireflies over a room rendered in cycles would be ok if fireflies rendered in internal and room in cycles, but if room would also be rendered in the internal then, first cycles materials wouldn't hold in the internal and second the room would be opaques, what would alpha do?

Comment: I would render the room in Cycles and the fireflies in Internal over a transparent background, with no cross-dependencies.