# Particle system not rendering in cycles

Tags: rendering, particles

I've been making a beauty and the beast animation for a school project. and I've created a particle system that sort of creates streaks coming from a single vertex however it will only show in 3D view solid mode. so it wont render in my final product could someone pls tell  me why? Sorry if it's obvious i am reasonably new to blender.[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't assign a renderable geometry to your particles. Halo materials are not supported under cycles

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes, you can render halos in cycles ,using point density in a domain.  See:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/blender-cycles-wont-render-halo-particles

Comment: @cegaton Hey didn't know that, always thought it was a a reminiscence from Blender Internal. Always learning :)

Answer (score 2):

Cycles cannot directly render particles. You can select Object in the Render particle properties panel to render each particle as a duplicated object or you need to use a different method of generating geometry from the particles. One such solution to generate trails from particles is defined in [How to add trailing light effect to finger tips?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94976/29586)