# Are Blender 2.8 Halo Particles meant to render? [EDIT: Or ANY particle, for that matter!]

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

That's it, really.

Are Blender 2.8 Halo mode Particles meant to be seen in render – Cycles, Eevee or otherwise?

I've been running whatever the latest-latest ver. of Blender 2.8 for Win10 64 bit is, over the last few weeks, and have seeN no evidence that the Halo setting is for anything other than setup, but does anybody know For Sure??

I completely understand that this IS software in development and that Things May Change, I'm just interested in whether to bother working around the issue or not.

Q

Comment: Halo particles are probably a leftover from Blender Internal render. They never worked in Cycles, they aren't supported for EEVEE either and are likely to get removed before 2.8 releases

Comment: Thank you – that's calming.

[EDIT] which makes stumbling across this one this morning all the more perplexing. Am I reading it wrong? 
https://developer.blender.org/T63056

Comment: The workaround is described here: [cycles, halo particles don't render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles) and [cycles won't render halo particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/blender-cycles-wont-render-halo-particles)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Eevee because I'm still working with Cycles even in 2.8, but in Cycles halo objects don't render.

The workaround I use is to render particles as objects. I either use planes with halo images mapped to them as textures, or I use tiny icospheres with an emission shader and use the compositor to make them glow.

Comment: Those work nicely under Eevee, too. It's just that I've seen halo particles render  _italic_sometimes_italic_, but not all the time – and never recently. I've got a couple of bits and pieces that look fine with a default halo setting, but I'd be quite happy to leave 'em on the back burner for a couple of months if things will be working when 2.8 goes live. If, however, that in't t'case, I''ll get on and add objects accordingly.