# Why is my model pink?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a model which was in cycles. When I shifted it to Blender Render it became pink. When I render it the color is fine but in object mode and edit mode it is pink. Someone help. It has no textures applied on it and I made a new material for it in Blender Render. Help...

Comment: the materials for cycles and blender render are not interchangeble.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal