# Switching from Blender Render to Cycles Render messes up materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm  trying to make a 360 degrees animation film for YouTube. I have to use Cycles Render because of the panoramic camera. I modeled everything and then noticed I was in Blender Render mode. When I switch to Cycles Render everything looks different, no textures or materials.

As far as I understand from googling - Cycles Render is a completely different engine and I guess I have to redo a lot to make everything look the same as in Blender Render mode.
Could anyone please suggest how to fix the issue, maybe there's a tutorial somewhere with the steps needed to recreate everything? Or maybe I made some stupid mistake?
Here are the images in Blender Render and Cycles Render.
[image: Blender Render]
[image: Cycles]

I tried the following script, but it didn't help:
https:// developer. blender .org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/materials_cycles_converter.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

Comment: related:   [how is cycles different than internal?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

 ---- [convert materials from internal to cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

 ---- [Mix different scenes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the post, I tried that script, even the new version and it ran without errors, but in the end it didn't fix much. Here's my project and the script I used: https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/o8H3cIicN%2BSZwpK29ygomA