# Texture made in cycles doesn't show on blender render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

it shows on cycle render but not on blender render.. what to do? here are the screen shots [image]

[image]

Comment: sadly, node based materials made in cycles do not work in the Blender Render, and viceversa.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55611/switching-from-blender-render-to-cycles-render-messes-up-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render