# Texture Disappeared in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

When I selected the *Blender Render*, there is no problem with the texture. When I change the render engine to *Cycles Render*, all the textures are gone.

[image]

I already unwrapped the mesh and mapped the texture onto it.

[image]

Now when I render the image in the camera, I got:

[image]

What is the reasone to make the texture disappeared in *Cycles Render*?

Comment: Materials in blender internal work totally different than in Cycles. **They are not interchageable** Related links: - [how is cycles different than internal?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal) - [convert materials from internal to cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)  - [Mix different scenes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender Internal and Cycles are two different render engines, each of them has it's own materials and shaders.
Objects that have BI materials will not render correctly in another render engine, that includes Cycles, so you need to reassign Cycles materials to your objects.
Your objects unwrap has nothing to do with what render engine you are using, so the good news is that you don't need to unwrap again.