# Material wont appear in blender render but it does in blender cycles

Tags: materials

I can make my material apear in Blender Render, but it does appear in Blender Cycles.
And im trying to make to make it appear in blender render so i can Bake it whit Full Render , just to have all the details in a PNG file or JPEG.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's not that simple... Apart being completely different renderers, Cycles si much more advanced than Blender render (aka internal), so you can't simply switch the renderer and expect to have advanced features on a less capable (and old) renderer. While the reverse is sometimes posslble (but not advisable, imho), the rendered should be the first choice in a project, when you must choose matrials at least, and then you should stick to it, due to this.

Comment: Then is there any way i could bake my texture into a PNG  whit the bump map , sharders basically  everything I've done in the nodes just in to one texture , in blender cycles ?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials are not interchangeable between render engines.

Cycles uses a completely different system to BI even down to how the light is treated. BI uses a diffuse - specular workflow and is not PBR. Cycles uses metallic -roughness and is PBR.

The best you can do is bake the cycles textures to maps then load them in to BI and adjust them that way.