# Not render sky texture?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I'm using a sky texture for environmental lightning. It gets rendered as background when I do that.
Can I prevent it from rendering, but still use it for environmental lightning?

Comment: Related, [Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Blender Internal:

**Method 1:**
You could disable *Sky* in *Properties > Render Layers > Layer*:

[image]

With *Sky* enabled:

[image]

With *Sky* disabled:

[image]

**Method 2:**
Another way is to set the *Alpha* to *Transparent* in *Render settings > Shading*:

[image]

This will give the same result as disabling *Sky* in *Render layers > Layers*.

## Cycles:

For cycles you could set the *Film* to *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*:

[image]

With *Transparent* disabled:

[image]

With *Transparent* enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Cycles

In Cycles can do that by using the *Light Path* node set to *Is Camera Ray* (You have to invert it otherwise it renders without affecting the lighting of the scene. The inverse of what you want.):
[image]

## Blender Internal

In Blender internal, you have to set the alpha to the sky, then you can put anything you want into the background. To render the sky as alpha:

1. Under the *Shading* tab of the *Render* panel, set alpha to *Transparent*.
2. Under the *Output* tab of the *Render* panel, set *Output* to *PNG* with *RGBA*
3. Render.

In the compositor, use the *Mix* node to add a background color/image:
[image].

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]