# Replace background while using HDRI for lighting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

How can I replace the background of my scene, but keep the reflections and lighting generated from my HDRI?

Comment: Render with transparent film. Go to Render Settings>Film and check the Transparent checkbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Not a duplicate as far as I can see, at least not of that question: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Answer (score 2):

Enable *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*:

[image]

Now the sky will render as alpha transparency when seen directly, but still illuminate and reflect off other objects.

Once you have a transparent background, it can easily be filled in with another image via an *Alpha Over* node:

[image]
<sub>The *Translate* node is used for some tweaks to the positioning of the background image.</sub>

Comment: Maybe it would be good to include a bit of information regarding compositing work involved. After all, the question was not about how to get a transparent background, but how to change the background without effecting the scene.

Comment: Much better! Although for simplicities sake, I would get rid of the translate node, but that's just me.

Comment: This was not helpful to me, can anyone please provide an video tutorial

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi What is unclear? I can't really help unless I know where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, my lake of knowledges where the issue, buy looking precisely to the images provided I was able to reproduce it. Thanks

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi Glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: Does this have to be made in the compositor? You can't do it straight in a world material so you can see it in the viewport?

Comment: @eobet Hm.. I think you could do it in a world material, yes. If you'd like to ask another question, comment a link to me here and I'll see if I can figure something out! (If you're still looking for a solution)

Comment: Thanks, found the answer here already actually (although the result gets slightly distorted): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/145396/38603

Comment: @eobet I'm glad! To solve the distortion you could try connecting a texture coordinate node (window) -> mapping node -> vector input of your image texture node.