# how to colorize the water?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I made a water simulation.

I also use an HDRI to light the scene because it is easy to use and looks great.

Unfortunately the water "mirrors" the HDRI background which isn't blue which looks kind of "bad". I want to have blueish color.

So i thought, i could add a blue plane around/under the water so it reflects the blue from there.

Unfortunately it does not (in Eevee).

Anybody an idea how to get what i want?

@Moonboots: Thank you very much for your answer. At least now i can change the color. ;) But... now my "water" looks like this (see image)

I hoped the water would somehow reflect that color that it still looks like water...

[image]

UPDATE2: @moonboots: i am sorry, but the file is too big because of HDRI i think, so blender stackexchange didn't work, your proposal does just accecpt until 24MB ...it is 105 MB ...so to be quick i used dropbox, hope you don't beat me

https://www.dropbox.com/s/03591rpn34wwgth/blue_water_test.blend?dl=0

Comment: Use the Light Path node: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145392/use-a-hdri-just-for-lighting-and-change-the-background-color?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thanks moonboots, i tried, with no luck, but i will keep on trying ;)

Comment: mmh I've just tried and it works fine, so maybe tell a bit more about where it fails

Comment: well...the water has still the color of the HDRI background, .....don't worry, i will try...if i know more i will update my question. Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: See my answer, I show the node setup, this is not the only solution but this one should work

Comment: please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: aye aye Sir! But i had to use dropbox :(. -> updated question

Comment: see my edit, if the problem is that the color is bad you can change the color or use a node setup with noise or another HDRI

Comment: alright.........

Comment: Also you may need to work a bit on the water material but it's another problem  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a node setup that works, use an *Input > Light Path > Is Glossy Ray* to reflect the color (or the HDRI) you want but you could use other methods as well:

[image]

From the file you share, if you want a nice color and reflect, just plug another HDRI in the second *Background*:

[image]

Comment: thank you!! Now i learned how to change the color, which i didn't know before and how to just use the lighting of HDRI. Unfortunately now the water doesn't look like water anymore (i updated my question)

Answer (score 1):

The water reflects the environment: The ocean looks blue on clear days and gray on cloudy ones.

Look for an HDRi that has clear sky in the area that is reflected by the water.

Or use a second HDRi that is used for reflections only.

Read:

[How to use multiple HDRIs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris)

Comment: i am sorry susu, but this is not a solution for me. This is a cheap workaround, which does not fullfil my needs, because I cannot exactly choose the colors i want to have, just the ones which provides the HDRI. But thanks for the answer anyway.