# How to get to the Render Output Panel

Tags: interface

I want to export my mesh as a transparent PNG. I found this [page](http://blendmo.blogspot.com/2012/09/export-transparent-png.html) that shows how to do that.

But first I need to get to the Render Output panel.  How do I get there?

I am using version 2.72b on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the right in the big section called the *Properties Editor*:

[image]

Comment: I must not have been using Cycles, because I did not have Film panel. Instead I had to go to Shading panel and select Alpha: Transparent in drop down. I also used these instructions http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent