# Bake texture from view

Tags: texture-baking

I have a wooden crate with textures and all. I want to turn this (Figure 1, see below) into this (Figure 2).

The only way I can think to explain it would be projection baking, where I project my 3D view unto a new image to get my desired image. I'm trying to lower my poly count so I need to take the second image's 3D view and actually turn it into an image, so that I can use a single poly on it instead of multiple.

It's hard to explain, but I'll try: if you just finished making a high-poly model with textures, and it's unwrapped and everything, then you make a low-poly model. If you switch to the high-poly front view, and were to take a picture, then that is what I would want the image to be for the low-poly.

| Figure 1: |
| --- |
| [image] |

| Figure 2 |
| --- |
| [image] |

Comment: You can render with a camera from the object side or create a low poly model and bake directly from high poly model to low poly model.

Comment: I have tried that with normal mapping, however when ever i try it with texture (im using blender render at the moment because i could not find a "texture" option in cycles) it just gives me white.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new material
2. Create a new texture
3. Now set your Type: to Image or Movie, Open up your Image then set your coordinates (under mapping) to UV
4. Lastly UV unwrap your mesh, unless it's already unwrapped then that's fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ohd thats what you mean. Yeah i can do that but thats different. It has to be in the exact was as front view. Not the uv wrap

Comment: try facing (what ever your obect is) and then UV unwrap it from view

Comment: I didnt know you could do that!! I will have to try that when i have time. Another way i thought to explain what i want would be if you scaled your front view down so it was completely flat and then could some how use that as your texture.

Comment: Try to rendering the image with a transparent background.
First create a camera and make it face directly to the object or image, then follow the steps in the below link. Lastly begin rendering then save the render by simply going to 'Image' then 'Save as Image'. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Or you could switch the cycles render and bake diffuse (make sure you UV unwrap it from project view). The save that image.

Comment: @EthanSmith make sure you highlight the whole object when baking.

Comment: Highlight? So i have to select all faces in uv image editor to bake? Or do you mean in the 3d viewport because if thats what you mean then i always do that.

Comment: Hmmm try uploading an image so I can better understand what's happening

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out how to do what I want but its glitchy and I need help. I kept my original uv map and made a second but unwrapped it from view. I then duplicated the object so I have two objects now. I set the original object to use the original uv map and the second object to use the projected uv map with a different material from the original. I then use cycles and select "diffuse color" as the thing I want to bake, then kept the original objects uv / texture image what I wanted it to be,  and created a new image and assigned it to the duplicated object. So now the original should have the desired texture and the duplicated object should have the default black image as its texture. I then enabled selected to active and hit bake and this is what I get. It works EXACTLY how I want it to be but part of it doesn't bake.