# Audio Visualization with Background Image

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am not able to render background image and audio visualization into one video. I have tried compositioning audio visualization(spectrum) and background image into one but the render gives me only images 0001.png, 0002.png and so on.

Here's how it looks in blender:

[image]

Here's what I get:

[image]

Basically if there's another way to render audio visualization with background image, please mention it. I have no experience in blender.

Comment: You need to render the sky with alpha, see this here (look to the second heading, Blender Render): http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1307/3127

Comment: Yeah this solved my problem. Thank you @GiantCowFilms

Comment: You could actually record the 3D screen view via OpenGL. This would render it exactly as you see it. Look at the bottom of the 3D view there's a little Film Clapper icon. It will render out in the format that you define in the scene render properties.