# Can I render each layer with transparent background?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

My question:

1. How can I export the PNG file ( like the attachment file ) from blender file?
2. How can I render each layer with transparent background?

I have a blender file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dfak4v5p8vyuq9/BC%20lending%20page62.blend?dl=0

[image]

Comment: what layers are you talking about?

Comment: Can I export each layer ( 1,2,3... ) in blender file? See attachment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps0x1qudcic3dxa/tweegy_landing_trans2-01%20%281%29.png?dl=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1st question:

**Rendering an image with transparency in **BLENDER INTERNAL****

1. First you have to tell blender not to render the background, or sky: Under "Render/Shading", switch alpha from "sky" to "transparent". Now only the objects in the scene will be rendered.
2. You must render to a file format that supports transparency, such as "PNG". Under "Render/Output", switch the file format to "PNG".
3. Make sure the image channel setting is "RGBA", not "BW" or "RGB". The A in RGBA stands for alpha, where the transparency information is stored in the PNG file.

[image]

Comment: Why can't I see Shading Section? https://www.dropbox.com/s/llb1ydsal2gdh66/Screenshot%20from%202015-11-13%2015%3A42%3A12.png?dl=0

Comment: I just downloaded your blend file and saw your using cycles! Your question has been answered before http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent. Also you have a large plane (used as a lightsource), blocking the "sky", or background. In Cycles, emitter objects get rendered. In Blender internal lights don't get rendered.