# Render Layer showing through other Layers

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

I have a question about render layers.
When I use the compositor to connect the layers together my first layer is always seen-through. For instance I can still see it in rendering even if the object is behind a wall and such. I'm pretty sure it is something simple that I'm missing so any help would be well appreciated

Screenshot of compositor:

[image: screenshot of compositor]

I've tried fiddling around with different nodes but nothing seems to work

Screenshot showing issue:

[image: Screenshot showing issue]

Comment: Most likely your render layer "Gobe" isn't transparent. Check *Transparent* in *Shading* rollout. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Comment: I've already tried that but nothing changed

Comment: I've changed to transparent and re-rendered, but still no changes, this probably shows what's happening in more detail: http://puu.sh/onVqF/1f1e6eaeaa.png

Comment: Another screenshot showing the same issue: the particle system is showing through the bookcases and floor: http://puu.sh/onVM8/efd583909b.png

Comment: Try checking "All Z" in the Render Layers pane.

Comment: Just checked it and no result :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after fiddling with the scene properties I somehow got it to work, by giving the layer that the object was on a mask layer and then ticking 'all Z' the objects stopped showing through other things. Thank you all for your help on this