# Cannot overlay or combine render layer with video

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

[image: the screenshot]

I am tying to combine a video and a blender model using the nodes in blender render mode but only the model or only the video is coming in the render.

Answer (score 3):

Your render doesn't have an alpha channel and is replacing the whole video.
if you are using Cycles , enable *Transparent* in your render options to have an alpha channel

[image]

For blender internal    set Alpha to *Transparent*

[image]

For more info, see [Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/12)