# Render glass distortion and not background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am doing a simple scene in Cycles with glass shards. I added a plane with the image I want as a background. However, I need to render only the glass shards, and their distortion of the background, and not the background it self.
How could this be done?

Comment: Does [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1307/5705) do what you want?

Comment: Not excatly. I've figured out transparent, but my background is either a background image (in the right menu) or a plane with the image, and they need to influence my glass shards while not rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way.

Select the background plane, go to its object settings, then scroll down to Cycles Settings. Uncheck 'Camera'.

[image]

That's it!

Here's the 3D view and the rendered view to demonstrate the effect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself :P

I needed to put the shards on layer 1, and background on layer 2. Then I shift-click both layers, so they are both visible. Then, I opened up render-layers and set the scene to layer 1 and layer 2 if they were not showing, and I selected only layer 1 under the "Layer" tab.