# Eevee Transparent Render is blank

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem and was wondering if this is a bug.

I've created some smoke that I would like to render with eevee. 
If I change the Alpha Setting in "Film" to "Transparent" I just get a blank, transparent PNG. If it's set to "Sky" I get the smoke rendered but with a black Background.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thx in advance,
Phil

Comment: EEVEE would be not fully developed yet as the Beta version is still in Development.

Comment: Blender has issues with unassociated alpha channels. Don't use PNG, use EXR as export format. Alternatively, premultiply the alpha with white. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50607/transparent-background-for-volumetric-smoke-bug and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69759/saving-gimps-alpha-color-values-in-blender/69783#69783 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/65154#65154

Comment: Hey cegaton, thx for the reply. I actually don't need it to be PNG - I tried it with EXR and get the same result. Every render is basically empty.
So could this be an eevee issue?