# Compositing alpha overlay

Tags: transparency

In the compositing layout the alpha over won't work. The background stays grey. How to make it transparent so that the background can be seen?

I followed this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l26kp1ETRk8

[image: img]

I wouldn't mind rendering just the image, and I did, but the strip alpha overlay doesn't work either, because it's a grey colour.

Comment: Please, don't plug the alpha channel into the Fac. The fac should be used to set the strength and is usually set to 1. If your image has alpha (which is the case), you can just unplug it. Otherwise, use the Set Alpha node to set the alpha. It basically does the same, but is kind of bad style.

Comment: The issue is that your original render layer has no alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the *render* tab -> *Shading* and change the *Alpha* from *Sky* to *Transparent*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set make the background transparent by setting it to Holdout in the world settings. Then you need to enable transparent rendering as shown [in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1307/24421). Short version: In the Render panel, set output type to RGBA and enable Transparent in Film.