# Blender pure video editor - overlay image with transparent areas

Tags: image, video, transparency

I just want to edit a video I recorded with my camera and add a logo onto it.

The logo is a PNG with transparent areas, and I want these areas to show the underlying video.

Unfortunately, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent) doesn't help me, it simply doesn't seem to change anything. When I click "render animation", the video shown contains the logo without transparent areas but with the "chess" background instead.

How do I do that?

Comment: ...which answer? and beside that missing link, can you share some setup detail, both about how how the png texture is set, and relevant vse settings?

Comment: Updated my question, sorry for the missing link. I was also able to find the answer. Thank you. ---- I'm a complete newbie in render. I don't know about "png texture" and unfortunately I don't know what "relevant vse settings" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it out.

When you add an image to the VSE (video sequence editor, where videos, audios, images, etc. appear as bars like a timeline), click the image bar with the right button. A properties panel will appear for that image, containing the filename and other information about it.

Under the **"Edit Strip"** section of that panel, change the **"Blend" combobox to "Over Drop"**. (Usually it starts with "cross").

That will make the image transparent areas actually transparent on the video.