# Checker Patterns appearing on the Render

Tags: rendering

[image]
File link-https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/5387
For some reason my render have these black and white checks. Please help me to remove them.  Thanks

Comment: There is no material assignd to those areas. You are seeing the default "Alpha" pattern. Meaning those areas are currently transparent.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be caused by the "use mist" in each material. I don't know why it works like that but disabling the "use mist" makes the objects solid.

[image]

Also that file isn't exactly great with scene and model work. You'd probably be better off creating your own sets. Forget about Blender Internal as the next big release won't even have it. Go with Cycles.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are rendering with transparent background. Essentially the opposite of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent) :)

To change this in your scene, (Blender Internal) go to the *properties panel* and change *Shading* alpha to **sky** rather than transparent.

[image]

Comment: Objects are transparent too. Which shouldn't be related to the skybox.