# Save text logo for external use

Tags: text-object, saving

I've created a 3D text with no animation, just text, and want to use it in my [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) when streaming. I don't know how to export it from blender to add it to OBS. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more about other software than about Blender.

Comment: this is blender

Comment: I want to save it on blender to use on other software

Comment: It is unclear what formats are supported by Open Broadcaster Software so it is hard to guess how it should be saved. Is it a picture that you need or a 3d model?

Comment: I want to save my blender 3d text as an image such as jpeg or png or bmp but don't know how

Comment: You will need to choose the render engine, setup a camera, some lighting, materials for your text, chose the render format and it's settings as well as dimensions of the image in the Properties Editor, Render Settings tab, render it (f12) and save the rendered image from the image editor (f3). If you needed more help it would be useful if you clarified what parts of the process you needed more help with.

Answer (score 2):

Using a non-animated image as a logo/overlay in an external program is generally pretty simple. From blender, all you should need to do it render it as an image with a transparent background. It should then be easy to add it to your program of choice. For example in OBS i found this: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/inserting-a-logo-while-recording-a-video.19133/

For more info on rendering a transparent background see: [Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent)