# How to render Alpha background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, error

I downloaded a file from blend swap edit it and I tried to render it with alpha channel but whenever I does this happens[image]

It look like it is rendering with alpha channel but it doesn't after when the rendering is completed this happends

[image]

You see when the render is completed there is a black background, what should I do.

Comment: Maybe you can find this answer helpful https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Comment: thanks but it I have tried it many times over and over but the result is same

Comment: Do you have a composting pipeline setup? Did you check the view alpha channel in the image viewer? (Draw channels to RGBA)

Comment: Thanks the problem was actualy Composting Pipeline, Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.9 you would would find the Transparency settings here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The problem was caused because of the compositing pipeline what I did was just unchecked the use nodes checkbox and boom, Finally the render I desired.

If uses these render setting for transparent video render

[image]

**Blender Version:** 2.79c

**Render Engine:** Cycles

**Render Format:** .mov (quicktime)