# My transparent background is black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I use Cycles, I *think*, because all the videos say it's Cycles.  Mine looks the exact same. and when I made my background transparent by going to:

**Properties>** **Render> Shading> Alpha**, and set it to **"Transparent."**

I'm pretty sure this is how you do it because I looked up a video and that's what he did to turn on transparent background.

*But*, my background is black for some reason, and I need it to be transparent because I'm using these models for a game I'm making.

Comment: you can put a screenshot of your configuration and say what version of blender you use

Comment: You need to go in Properties > Render > Film, then activate the Transparent option

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! I guess I was just doing it wrong. Thanks again for showing me how to! (:

Comment: @moonboots Nevermind, Film isn't in my render properties. Also, how do I post a screenshot? I know how to get a screenshot, I just don't know how to post it. (Sorry, I'm pretty new.) XD

Comment: So you're using Blender Render? You'll have the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! I guess I just didn’t set it to RGBA.