# How to render an image with holdout material in Cycles 2.8?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

thats almost litterally the question asked here but these don't seem to be working with 2.80
[Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent)

i have PNG, Rgba, 8bit, 15% compression  and the holdout material still renders as black.

[image]

Comment: Did you enable film> Transparent in the scene settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable *World background* transparency.

It's in *Render Tab > Film > Transparent*
Check *✔ Transparent* and you're done.

[image]

[image]