# How can I render with a transparent background in 2.82?

Tags: rendering, transparency

Trying to render PNG's and I can only render with a white background!  I've checked Transparent;selected RGBA;tried both Filmic and Standard under Color Management...nothing changes render with white background.

I've tried Eevee and Cycles, to no avail. Really frustrated - can someone please help?!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent/1307?r=SearchResults#1307

Comment: Have you made sure that there is no hidden object in the viewport that is still rendered in the background of the scene? Could you post a screenshot of your user interface?

Comment: Thanks, Duarte, but all is good now.  The PNG file reflected a white background; however, when it was opened in Gimp/PhotoShop, etc., it actually had a transparent background.  Apparently, Blender 2.82 "renders" with either a white or black background, even though "transparent" is checked??